# Jump when loading fonts in NextJS 13.4.x

Tags: optimization, next.js, webfonts

Local font is loaded, path in public directory.
Development mode.
Disable cache in browser/network flag is set opposite.
As a result, when the page is reloaded, the font jumps. That is, it is loaded again and it is noticeable. Optimization crashed.
Rolled back to next 13.1.6, install @next/font 13.1.6 experimental: { appDir: true } - fonts are loaded without a jump.

**src/app/layout.tsx**

```
import { FC, ReactElement } from 'react'

import { Metadata } from 'next'
import localFont from 'next/font/local'

import { mainTitle } from '@constants/staticData.consts'

import Footer from '@components/layouts/Footer'
import Header from '@components/layouts/Header'

import { IPropsWithChildren } from '@interfaces/common.types'

import '@styles/main.css'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: mainTitle,
  description: 'Временное описание',
  icons: '/favicon.svg'
}

const moula = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: '../../public/assets/fonts/moula-regular.woff',
      weight: '400',
      style: 'normal'
    },
    {
      path: '../../public/assets/fonts/moula-regular.woff',
      weight: '400',
      style: 'normal'
    },
    {
      path: '../../public/assets/fonts/moula-semibold.woff2',
      weight: '600',
      style: 'normal'
    },
    {
      path: '../../public/assets/fonts/moula-semibold.woff',
      weight: '600',
      style: 'normal'
    },
    {
      path: '../../public/assets/fonts/moula-bold.woff',
      weight: '700',
      style: 'normal'
    },
    {
      path: '../../public/assets/fonts/moula-bold.woff',
      weight: '700',
      style: 'normal'
    }
  ],
  variable: '--font-moula'
})

const RootLayout: FC<IPropsWithChildren> = ({
  children
}): ReactElement => (
  <html lang='ru' className={ `${moula.variable}` }>
    <body className='font-moula text-large text-white bg-blue-960'>
      <Header />
      <main>{ children }</main>
      <Footer />
    </body>
  </html>
)

export default RootLayout
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
// ... //
fontFamily: {
        moula: [ 'var(--font-moula)', ...fontFamily.sans ]
      },
// ... //
```

It looks very much like it's a bug. I wrote to [bug report](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50938)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should directly add `moula.className` into this code without changing in `tailwind.config.js`

```
const RootLayout: FC<IPropsWithChildren> = ({
  children
}): ReactElement => (
  <html lang='ru'>
  <body className={moula.className}>
      <Header />
      <main>{ children }</main>
      <Footer />
    </body>
  </html>
)

export default RootLayout
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. The font loads with a jump, besides in TailwindCSS it is necessary to throw a variable one way or another

Comment: @Gabber can you share the link by using the stackblitz or code sandbox website.

Comment: [project files](https://mega.nz/file/wXp3QILb#QG6oRZH_slcTE6_lG-P4e7F_NrVjRZjfGRh3NF7Tu_g)  - in my case, only so.

Comment: @Gabber I checkout your code and their is no lag between the fonts and i just try your code in development and production in chrome and firefox browser.
Try this:
   `<body className={`${moula.className} text-large text-white bg-blue-960`}></body>`

Comment: I told you, I tried it, but it doesn't work. Besides, I need a variable for TailwindCSS. The problem is not in the browser, in my case, the font is cached in firefox, if you remove the caching of requests, then the jump is observed in browsers

Comment: sent a message to you via your personal website

Comment: I didn't get any message 

Comment: write your email, I will send you